# Onchange event in a text input behaviour in JavaScript to immediately register changes upon typing?

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom-events, method-call

I would like be able to register the changes on the web page from the text field `id=frm1` without clicking on the page or on the Check button while the cursor is still blinking on the text field. I am currently using onchange event and it apparently does not register changes until I click out of the text field. Also any advice on the quality of the code/better/other way of doing this would be appreciated. I am also wondering why the value of `element[0]` is undefined. I am a beginner in JavaScript.

```
 // JavaScript source file Operator.js

function checkNumber(document) {
    var formNumber = document.getElementById("problem1");
    var txt = "even";
    var number = formNumber.elements[1].value;
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        txt = "even";
    } else {
        txt = "odd";
    }
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = txt;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>HmwkOperators</title>
    <script src="Operators.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="problem1" action="form_action.asp">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Problem1 verify number if it is odd:</legend>
            Number: <input type="text" onchange="checkNumber(document)" id="frm1" autocomplete="off"><br>
            <p id="Result"></p>
            <input type="button" value="Check" onclick="document.Result.reload(true)">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are several different event usable for this requirement. This may help you decide which is most appropriate for your situation..  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input#Related_Events

Comment: Also, here is a fiddle showing how each event occurs. http://jsfiddle.net/girlie_mac/5Assc/

Comment: @PetarDrianov The input event is good for recent browsers - however it isn't supported in older versions of IE (8, 7 etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`onkeyup`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onkeyup) event instead:

> "The `onkeyup` event handler captures the moment at which a previously
>   pressed key is released while focus is on the element to which the
>   onkeyup attribute is applied."

In this case:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="checkNumber(document)" id="frm1" autocomplete="off">
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SUJ8h/)

---

Note though, that it's always better to keep your markup (HTML) and scripts (JavaScript) separate.

Instead, you could use **[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)**:

```
var el = document.getElementById("frm1");
el.addEventListener("keyup", checkNumber, false);
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SUJ8h/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would have been nice to give me a link how to separate HTML and JavaScript better. Is it to add event listener  like Weber suggested?

Comment: @PetarDrianov Updated, hopefully that helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

AS stated in my comments, there are several events that may fill your requirements with varying results.

[OnKeyUp](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/10920) - occurs when the user releases a key from its depressed position.

[OnInput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oninput) -  is raised when an  element value changes.

*[OnChange](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/javascript/10912) - Already tried, doesn't fit criteria*

```
input.addEventListener("{TYPE"}, YourTrackingMethod);
```

[FIDDLE TO TEST WITH](http://jsfiddle.net/girlie_mac/5Assc/)

My opinion is that the key up event is what you are looking for, **but beware browser differences in handling and event information.**

Comment: Why is `OnKeyUp` better than `OnInput` for this situation?

Comment: @Marathon55 - I agree - I think onInput is what is needed because that works even on paste or dragging text into the text input. I think the problem with `onInput` though is consistent browser support - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input#Browser_compatibility